# Asp. Net MVC private member value lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am me to asp. Ne MVC I am using N_layrs architecture ( usiness, service, validation, data and presintation layers). I created a controller to view some data. I implemented the presentation interface to the controller abd I  alled the display method (this method wil retrieve the data from the system layers and call the presentation interface method to gi e me the value) in the implemented interface method I assine the back items variable to local private variable but when I assign this list to View method the value be null.

```
    public class AgreementController : Controller, IListView<IList<AgreementModel>>
{
    private static ListPresenter<AgreementModel> _agreementListPresenter;

//This is the private member
    private IList<AgreementModel> _items;
    public RequestType RequestType
    {
        get
        {
            return RequestType.FindAll;
        }
    }

    public string ListErrorMessage
    {
        set
        {
        }
    }

    // GET: Agreement
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    //Some unity code for DI
        IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IListView<IList<AgreementModel>>, AgreementController>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<Service<IBusinessService<AgreementModel>, AgreementModel>>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IBusinessService<AgreementModel>, BusinessService<AgreementModel>>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IRepository<AgreementModel>, AgreementRepository>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<Service<IBusinessService<PlanModel>, PlanModel>>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IBusinessService<PlanModel>, BusinessService<PlanModel>>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IRepository<PlanModel>, PlanRepository>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IValidator<AgreementModel>, AgreementValidator<AgreementModel>>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IValidator<PlanModel>, PlanValidator<PlanModel>>();

    //Create the Presenter this will fire DisplayList
    _agreementListPresenter = unityContainer.Resolve<ListPresenter<AgreementModel>>();
        _agreementListPresenter.Display();
    //The value here is NULL
        return View(_items);
    }

    public void DisplayList(IList<AgreementModel> items)
    {
    //I recieved vale here and it is OK
        _items = items;
    }
}
```

}

> This solved my issue

```
unityContainer.RegisterInstance<IListView<IList<AgreementModel>>>(this);
```

> By this I regester the current controller object insted of createing new one

Comment: Instead of a description of the code, please post the actual code..

Comment: Please post your code. It is hard to tell the issue without your code.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: my eyes are burning!!!! delete the code!!! delete the code!!!!

Comment: @Ewan Why? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer.

It looks like you instantiate a new AgreementController via Unity, which presumably sets its own item list somewhere in your million classes.

But the View is sent the list of items from the Controller which you have called. Not the one you instanciated.

Long answer.

You should move all you dependency injection code to your App Startup or Global.ascx point. Its called when the app starts up, not when a page is requested.

Your AgreementController should have a constructor with parameters for the services it needs. Unity will create the controller and inject the services that you have registered in global.ascx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already call the unity from global. Asax but I added it here to explan what happens in the hidden code. What I am wondering is that the value lost after the called. I received it at  DisplayList (this called after _agreementListPresenter.Display())

Comment: maybe post your _actual_ code then? but i still think its the same problem, you are in Controller A and calling the Method on Controller B

Comment: I think I need to pass the curren controller to tbe presentation layer I did it here (unityContainer.RegisterType<IListView<IList<AgreementModel>>, AgreementController>();) but it create new controller object. How I can pass the curren controller(this) object via unity inster of new object?

Comment: follow my instructions and inject the services into the controller with a constructor. dont use .Resolve ever

Comment: I found a method called RegisterInstance and it is workong fine withe my code... Can you explane why I shouldn't use.Resolve?  and if I don't use it how I can take the advantage from the unity?

Comment: unity automatically resolves the controllers when they are needed.

Comment: But I am not resol e the controller I resolve the ListPresenter object

Comment: why are you arguing with me? try it out